# How to display Contact Form 7 submission value output on redirect page?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am facing this issue very long time.I just want to display contact form 7 submission values output on my different redirect page the url is (http://web.softwarestar.in/submit.php). After submission redirection is working but data is not showing.

This is my form url: http://success.evolvertech.com/?page_id=2400

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code ,

```
on_sent_ok: "var yourname = $('.wpcf7 input[name=your-name]').val();var youremail = $('.wpcf7 input[name=your-email]').val();var cf7favorite = $('.wpcf7 input[name=cf7-favorite]:checked').val();location = '/thank-you/?yourname='+yourname+'&youremail='+youremail+'&cf7favorite='+cf7favorite;"
```

Change location with your submit page URL.

Also show data on that page,

```
$yourname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["yourname"]);
$youremail = htmlspecialchars($_GET["youremail"]);
$cf7favorite = htmlspecialchars($_GET["cf7favorite"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . Can i put this code in Additional Settings?

Comment: ok_sent_ok code in additional setting and rest on your submit page template

Comment: on_sent_ok: "var yourname = $('.wpcf7 input[name=your-name]').val();location = 'http://web.softwarestar.in/submit.php?yourname='+yourname;"

Comment: I think script is conflict. Please Replace $ to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://www.url.com';"
```